# phoneGap files not found in QT-creator

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-creator, cordova, carbide

i'm new to Qt, i just install all in one QT-SDK beta with QT-creator as described [here](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Qt_Quick_Start). I tried to import PhoneGap example files from [there](http://wiki.phonegap.com/PhoneGap-Symbian-%28Qt%29) (I use Qt-creator coz when I try to do it on Carbide, as described, it said that my EPOCROOT is wrong, but it isn't). When I want to debug or run project it said that there are some files missing, but i see them in files-tree ([look](http://images.virtualdesign.pl/images/61170qt.jpg)). Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on PhoneGap Qt and am currently in the process of upgrading PhoneGap Qt to use the latest Qt Release, as well as the latest Qt Mobility Libraries. Hopefully once this is complete things will work smoother for you. Keep an eye on the github repository for updates.